# Get website options from database on any route calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I want to get data from the Option table in my database when any route calls,

for example:  I Have a one static class called Option, in this class, I have a Title property.

I Want to get the title from the database for all requests.

I Add the Following code to `Startup -> ConfigureServices`

```
OptionService optionService = new OptionService(new DatabaseContext());

Option.Title = optionService.Get("title").Value;
```

but its get title from website one time forever!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use middleware like this. It's executed for every request.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            OptionService optionService = new OptionService(new DatabaseContext());
            Option.Title = optionService.Get("title").Value;
            await next.Invoke();
            // Do logging or other work that doesn't write to the Response.
        });
    }
}
```